# Snowflake: why query is retried twice during resource contention

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake query running on a medium warehouse is re-ran twice during resource contention. Can someone share any reference on how snowflake fails and then retries the execution of the same query. What is the advantage we are gaining with this approach?

Step 1
Step 2
Step 1002
Step 2002

Answer (score 2):

As it has been explained to us by support: When a query fails due to internal errors, snowflake retries the query but on the prior software stack versions. To see if the failure is part of a recent update on their side.

You do get the joy of paying for both runs. If there is happening a lot, you should open a support case as there is a repeating bug that should be addressed or worked around. Under some situations we have had the long dead time (the failure case) refunded.